# how can change (America/Chicago) time into indian(Asia/Kolkata) time

Tags: php, timezone

`$row['created']` <- a variable get date/time into Database .
`$row['created'] have  time like 2016-10-07 01:31:42 .` and time zone`(America/Chicago)` . 
so I would like show  time according Indian time zone . I am using code shown in below but is not working.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row['created']);
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    echo date('r', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to save as indian time.

```
<?php
    $date=date_create('2016-10-07 01:26:56',timezone_open("America/Chicago"));
    echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:sP")."<br>";

    date_timezone_set($date,timezone_open("Asia/Kolkata"));
    $indiatime = date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:sP") . "<br>";
    echo $indiatime ;
?>
```

Comment: Anytime @MKB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use [timezone_open](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) and date_format

```
$timestamp = "2016-10-07 01:31:42";
$date = date_create($timestamp, timezone_open('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";  //echo 2016-10-07 01:31:42+05:30
```

or

```
$timestamp = "2016-10-07 01:31:42";
$user_tz = 'Asia/Kolkata';    
echo $timestamp. "\n"; // echo 2016-10-07 01:31:42

$schedule_date = new DateTime($timestamp, new DateTimeZone($user_tz) );
$schedule_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$triggerOn =  $schedule_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $triggerOn; // echo 2016-10-06 20:01:42
```

[**DEMO**](https://3v4l.org/L7G6O)

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime class. Look at this [DateTime doc example](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php#example-2526).

```
$date = new DateTime($row['created'], new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

This will let you jump between timezones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql, you do this also:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(created,'America/Chicago','Asia/Kolkata');
```

Instead of coding in php, when you fetch data from database you may be use the following query: `select field1,field2,created from <tablename> where <yourCondition>`. Instead of doinf so update your query this way:

`select field1,field2,CONVERT_TZ(created,'America/Chicago','Asia/Kolkata') from <tablename> where <yourCondition>`

Comment: This is a mysql inbuild function to convert time zone: CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz); using this you can convert date zone wise.for more details please try this link : `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz`

Comment: ok thanks......I would not like change in database ......i want to change in echo time...

Comment: some student gave right answer  Bartek Rudnik and aalam see